# Assign PHP Variable to HTML button to change results of table been fetch by mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a button that will link my checklog.php page which is a table being pulled from MySQL to dayview.php which is a copy of the same table, I'm trying to pre-set the value of my button to today's date. So users can get a day view of the table. The button works but I'm not able to make it pull data just for today's day it just pulls the data for all the dates. Both checklog.php and fayview.php are a mirror copy of each other.

```
 <?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

 $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
 ?>


 <html>
 <li><a type"hidden" name="date" value="<?php $date ?>" class="btn btn- 
 success" href="dayview.php" style="color:white;">Day View</a></li
 </html>
```

I want to click the "Day View" button on checklog.php and be able to see that days view on dayview.php.

Comment: Your HTML is wrong. The `a` tag is used for anchors and if you want to pass the date by url, you should pass it as a GET parameter of the url (in href attribute of tag). If you plan to pass the date in a form with a hidden input, you should use `input` tag instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
 date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

 $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
 ?>


 <html>
 <li>
<form action ="dayview.php" method="post">
<input type"hidden" name="date" value="<?php $date ?>" class="btn btn- 
 success" style="color:white;">
</form>
</li>
 </html>
```

Try this.

The `<a>`tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.